# Excel VBA linking two cells with hyperlink

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I am currently using this code to link two cells which are user selected with the help of inputboxes.

The problem is, that the cells selected cannot contain formulas and are also not allowed to have figures in them. The code only works on cells that contain text (i.e. "some text").
In the case that I do have figures or formulas within the cells I want to link I get *"run-time error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument"* pointing me to the `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add` part of the code.

Anyone an idea why this code is not working on cells with formulas or numeric values?

```
Sub InsertHyperlinks(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim FirstHyperlink As Range
Dim SecondHyperlink As Range
Dim FirstSheet As Worksheet
Dim SecondSheet As Worksheet


Set FirstHyperlink = Application.InputBox("Please select first cell to contain hyperlink" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
"NOTE: Hyperlinks can only be added on text and not on cells containing formulas!", "Hyperlink 1 selection", Type:=8)

If FirstHyperlink Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
Else
Set FirstSheet = FirstHyperlink.Worksheet
End If

Set SecondHyperlink = Application.InputBox("Please select second cell to contain hyperlink", "Hyperlink 2 selection", Type:=8)

If SecondHyperlink Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
Else
Set SecondSheet = SecondHyperlink.Worksheet
End If
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=FirstHyperlink, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & SecondSheet.Name & "'" & "!" & SecondHyperlink.Address, TextToDisplay:=FirstHyperlink.Value

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=SecondHyperlink, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & FirstSheet.Name & "'" & "!" & FirstHyperlink.Address, TextToDisplay:=SecondHyperlink.Value

End Sub
```

When using the macro recorder and linking two cells (numeric or with formula) I get basically the same piece of code for the hyperlink section, that's why I don't understand why I get a run-time error with my piece of VBA?!

Comment: "*this code is not working*" is not a good error description. Do you get any error messages and if so where in the code?

Comment: turn off `On Error Resume Next` and check if your code generates errors

Comment: the code you provided works for me, the only difference is I am not calling it from ribbon

Comment: @Peh: I updated my description including the run-time error I get when I remove 'on error resume next'.

Comment: @avb: Even if I call it not from the ribbon I get a run-time error when I try to link cells that are not containing text (i.e. formulas or figures)

Comment: I did it on a cell containing formula, what kind of runtime error it is?

Comment: on which line the error occurs?

Comment: @avb: I also tried it on a formula but it is still not working. I get run-time error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument. It occurs on the ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add part of my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is produced by `TextToDisplay:=SecondHyperlink.Value` not because it contains formula, but because it contains formula returning non-text type.

Replacing it with

```
TextToDisplay:=CStr(SecondHyperlink.Value)
```

solves problem.

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks! Didn't know that I had to convert it to a string again!